# How to create a window within a UWP app to enter in detail/properties information

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but I don't know the exact terminology for what I'm wanting.

Essentially in my C# xaml uwp app I have a couple objects that need to have details added to them, kind of like file properties. I have a button that I would like to open up another window (still part of the app), just to enter in the properties. I just don't know the terminology to look up what this window would be called or find documentation for it. So the exact same as when you're in a file browser and you open the properties of a file; it opens in a little extra window that you can drag around.

I don't want to be able to use the main window while the properties window is open, and of course they need to be able to transfer data between one another.

In my previous apps I've simply made a grid that appears over everything else in the middle of the app and shaded the outer area. A workaround as I didn't know how to do this.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hi, If the answer works, please accept anfd vote, in order others can find the answer conveniently. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `Dialog` refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/dialogs.

Dialog controls are modal UI overlays that provide contextual app information. They block interactions with the app window until being explicitly dismissed. They often request some kind of action from the user.